# how to recover submited post data in cpanel

Tags: php, post, cpanel

In user registration by mistake in database mobile no column i took integer instead of varchar and its not giving me the proper number and this data is very important for me so is there any way to get proper data back. my form method is post.

Answer (score 0):

if you open the nginx log,you can according to nginx log to recovery the data. because the nginx log have the request details

Comment: where i can find this log?

Comment: This is not true in general. POST request bodies are not logged.